# LUIS builtin.number entity parsing

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, azure-language-understanding

I am looking to integrate LUIS in my bot and one of the elements I need is a number, so naturally I wanted to use the `builtin.number` entity.

I quickly discovered that while the entity is recognized, the output it provides is still a string value that I need to parse in order to get my number out of it. This might work well for "12", "5", "10", but it stops working when I get "four", or "twenty eight".

Is there something I'm missing here? Or is this the expected behavior and I should either not support written numbers or implement my own parsing methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it should be matching to builtin.number whether its a numeral or a digit representation, but currently it does return that back as a string and you'll need to do your own parsing on top of that if you always need to match them into a integer format (or the like).

I think adding this capability is a great idea and would encourage you to add it to our feature backlog on uservoice: https://cognitive.uservoice.com/